# How to optimize a query with wildcards in WHERE clause with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

Currently, I have this query

```
SELECT field1 FROM table1 
WHERE field1 LIKE '%foo%' 
LIMIT 20
```

Is it more efficient to have the following query ?

```
SELECT field1 FROM table1 
WHERE 
field1 LIKE 'foo'  OR 
field1 LIKE 'foo%' OR 
field1 LIKE '%foo%' 
LIMIT 20
```

**SQL VERSION** (Sorry I should have mentionned earlier)

MySQL 5.5 with innoDB engine on a shared hosting. With this configuration I cannot use a FULLTEXT index (**Fulltext Index** available from MySQL v5.6 on innoDB)

**MY DETAILED OBJECTIVE**

I need to find 20 records containing a *word*. Most of the time, the word will match exactly the value in the field, i.e. see table:

```
|  **field1**  |  **search**  |
|    record1   |    foo       |
|    record2   |    fooziness |
|    record3   |    other1    |
|    record4   |    foo       |
|    record5   |    other2    |
|      ...     |      ...     |
```

I know that `'word'` OR `'word%'` use the INDEX while the last `'%word%'` do not.

Will the query optimizer first try to find records with `'word'` OR `'word%'` and save the inefficient search of `'%word%'` if 20 `'word'` are found ?

Comment: Why you dont test it and check for the explain plan? [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: btw your second query isnt ok. You have to write `field1 = 'foo' or field1 LIKE 'foo%' or field1 LIKE '%foo%'`

Comment: I do not have enough data yet in the table :-)

Comment: Searching for '%foo%' implies string analysis that will check on the occurrence of this anywhere in the string, which will be slower than checking for 'foo%' at the start of the string. if the foo is always at the start then personally I would opt for 'foo%' over testing the value for an occurrence anywhere.

Comment: @jimmy8ball You miss the question. Sometimes there is enough `foo%` to fill the 20, but sometimes doesnt and op want to bring `%foo%`. to complete

Comment: @gentleboy Well I thing adding 20 foo isnt difficult ;)

Comment: one question that hasn't been asked is that, are these values predetermined? if so can these not be broken off into a dimension table and given an integer value id you could then use this to filter on instead of testing strings?

Answer (score 3):

This is much easier for you to test than for us to answer - especially as the actual query is probably much more complex than you show.

However...

According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html), limit can optimize a query, but mostly when using order by. That makes sense, because it's likely that there will be multiple "where" clauses and the limit clause won't necessarily know which ones are affected by the limit clause.

I have cheated with a similar query by doing the following:

```
( SELECT field1, 1 as quality FROM table1 
    WHERE field1 = 'foo'  
) union
( SELECT field1, 2 as quality FROM table1 
    WHERE field1 LIKE 'foo%'
) union
( SELECT field1, 3 as quality FROM table1 
    WHERE field1 LIKE '%foo%'
)    
order by quality 
LIMIT 20
```

This is much less readable, but did trick the optimizer into abandoning the query once it had found 20 records. Not sure if that works anymore.

Of course, if performance matters to you, using MySQL [Full text searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) is much faster, and much less fragile.

Comment: You are right, the query is more complex with many joins. Cannot use Fulltext index as MySQL 5.5 with innoDB (sorry for not mentionning).

Comment: I thought a simple change would do the trick but it seems more complicated. I tested and as of now it seems you got the only solution. I think I have to rewrite completely my queries soon.

Comment: I added parens so that the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` would apply to the `UNION`, not the last `SELECT`.

Comment: Recommend `UNION ALL` since there is no chance of dups, and it is faster.